# How to get an array from this line?

Tags: c, string

so i have the following line

```
BOOK_NAME_VALUE STRING Programming
```

i need to make an array contain this

```
a[0] = "BOOK_NAME";
a[1] = "VALUE";
a[2] = "STRING";
a[3] = "Programming";
```

the 2nd value of the array is the last part of the 1st part of the line;
the line separator is white space ' '
the 1st part separator is '_'

so any idea ??

**UPDATE**

i did this for the 2nd separation process,, need shorter way ??

```
#include<string.h>

char **str_tok(char *str,char* d){
    char *out[2];
    char *s;
    char *c;
    int toks = noToks(str,d);
    int i = 0;

    s = strtok(str,d);
    i++;
    while(i != toks){
        strcat(s, d);
        c = strtok(NULL,d);
        i++;
        strcat(s,c);
    }
    strcpy(out[0],s);
    c = strtok(NULL,d);
    strcpy(out[1], c);

    return out;
}

int noToks(char *str,char *d){
    int c = 0;

    while(*str)
        if(*str == *d){
            c++;
            str++;
        }
    return c;
}
```

Comment: You may want to move the `str++` in the function `noToks` outside the `if` and inside the `while`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at `strtok` function, that is used to split strings according to a set of specified delimiters.

Read [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strtok/) to find the documentation of the function and some examples.. basically you call

```
char *cur = strtok(your_string," ");
```

to obtain the first string and then you can keep calling the function with a `NULL` argument to obtain successive pieces:

```
while (cur != NULL) {
  // do whatever
  cur = strtok(NULL," ");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First **split the string by spaces**, which will give three strings (array).
Then simply **find the last '_' in the first string** in the strings array from above.
Combine all into a new array.

I'd put some code but this is terribly simple and if you're learning C then I suggest look for the functions yourself. I gave you the direction.

Hope it helps.